# IMDS in ECS Task without Exposing Instance Role Credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

In our ECS cluster running with EC2 instances we would like our tasks to be able to access the metadata server (169.254.169.254) without exposing the instance role credentials available through metadata on the task:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/ <INSTANCE_ROLE_NAME>
```

I am aware of IMDSv2 but I am not sure how this could solve our problem in this specific case. Another solution could be to simply disable IMDS within tasks but we need to obtain the EC2 instance within it.

Would there be a workaround / solution to our problem that would allow us to benefit from the metadata without exposing the instance role credentials ?

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear. How exactly do you want to use tasks roles without accessing them?

Comment: @Marcin Sorry I edited in an attempt to make it clearer. The metadata server is accessible through the instance and task hosted on the instance. We want the task to be able to access the metadata info without having access to the instance role credentials (through URL provided in OP). Task role is out of scope for this issue.

Comment: So why do you assign task role to your task if you don't want it to be used?

Comment: @Marcin must have made myself misunderstood. Task role is irrelevant in this case and I don't think I mentioned it (perhaps was it mistaken with instance role ?). Regardless of the task role, the instance role will be accessible through the metadata server, which we want to prevent